# Exponential equation that's been bothering me: $(2^x)^{x-1}=1024$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Equation: $(2^x)^{x-1}=1024$

What I did was:
$(2^x)^{(x-1)}=2^{10}$

$x(x-1)=10$

$x^2-x=10$

$x^2-x-10=0$

And proceeded to use Bhaskara, with the final result of
$\frac{1\pm \sqrt{41}}{2}$

I've tried to resolve but the output for $+$ and $-$ results from here onwards don't give me what I need; I have tried to check changing the $x$ in the equation to those results, and it doesn't match to $1024$ as final result. What should I do?

Comment: The way you have written it the equation is a bit ambiguous, (2^x)^x-1=1024 could mean $(2^x)^x-1=1024$ or $(2^x)^{x-1}=1024$. From what you wrote in the rest of your questions, I suppose you meant the latter, so I have edited the post accordingly..

Comment: Oh yeah, I was trying to write the second following the format but it didn't output what I wanted and just left it raw, probably skipped that while looking the guide, thanks for editing it back.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write $$2^{x(x-1)}=2^{10}$$ so you will get $$x(x-1)=10$$
By the quadratic formula we get $$x_{1,2}=\frac{1}{2}\pm\sqrt{\frac{1}{4}+10}$$
$$\frac{1}{4}+10=\frac{1+4\cdot 10}{4}=\frac{41}{4}$$

Comment: Can you explain the proccess to get that result? I'm sorry but I'm somehow understanding and at the same time not, feels like I'm lost, maybe vacations are paying off

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean exactly, solving the quadratic?

Comment: If the two bases are equal so the exponents must be equal

Comment: Didn't expect such quick response, also, I meant parting from this: $\frac{1\pm \sqrt{41}}{2}$
And how would you end up with 1/2 and 1/4, I feel stupid right now lol

Answer (score 1):

We have

$$(2^x)^{x-1}=2^{10} \implies 2^{x^2-x}=2^{10} \implies x^2-x=10$$
$$\implies x_{1,2}=\dfrac{1\pm\sqrt{1+4\cdot 10}}{2}=\dfrac{1\pm\sqrt{41}}{2}.$$

So your answer is correct. You can verify it with [wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2%5E(x*(x-1))%3D1024).

Comment: Yes, until there it's fine, but how do I verify? Maybe I'm typing in the calculator the wrong way and that's why, but I can't get to 1024

Comment: @Hareka: I think you are not typing it correctly into your calculator ... see link in my answer.

Comment: Nevermind, I was killing myself over it and probably due to my lack of sleep I just didn't see a digit or two clearly and been acting stupidly for a while now lol, it doesn't give an exact 1024, but it's still, I guess there's a margin of error due to the calculator not being able to output the exact precise number due to the size of said number, Idk

Comment: Also, you have my thanks, I'd have continued like this otherwise...

Comment: @Hareka: I checked the solutions with my CASIO fx-991DE PLUS and it gave an exact result of $1024$ in both cases. Could you provide a photo how your calculator screen input looks like?

Comment: https://pasteboard.co/I71rtja.jpg and https://pasteboard.co/I71ra5E.jpg did them in an app right now, not my calc but it's the same number (although, probably shorter)

Comment: So, I still think I'm wrong after I tried the solution below, it does give an exact 1024, I don't know what did I just do, but it's too late in the morning as for me to be cheking my notebook once again, I'll try something out later

Comment: @Hareka: You are using approximations and not the exact expressions. You need to type $0.5\pm 0.5\sqrt{41}$ into your calculator.

Comment: I don't get why $0.5\pm0.5√41$ would make it any more exact, in fact the result in decimals is the same. Or perhaps, was I supposed to use, for ex., $\frac{1\pm√41}{2}$ as x, all together and not use the irrational number that it outputs? If so, I've made a fool of myself

Comment: @Hareka You calculator gives $\sqrt{41}$ only with finite precision.